# XeLaTeX - gb4e example numbering in footnotes - Interaction with polyglossia package?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, linguistics, gb4e, bidi

I thought the `gb4e` package for linguistic example typesetting would provide automatic switching of the numbering scheme between main text examples and examples in footnotes. This is not the behavior I am currently getting from my MWE below. I.e., what exactly do I have to do to ensure that examples in the main text get the "standard" Arabic numbers, and examples in footnotes are under an independent numbering scheme (e.g., Roman)?

And a bigger problem: When I use the `polyglossia` package to define further languages for use within the document, XeLaTeX does not even use two independent counters for main text examples and footnote examples. Any advice on this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Devanagari MT}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Nafees}


\begin{document}

This is a test.

\begin{exe}
\ex
{
\gll Ein jeder Hund bellt.\\
{\sc art}.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} every.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} dog.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} bark.{\sc pres}.{\sc 3p}.{\sc sg}\\
\trans `Every dog barks.'
}
\label{ex-1}
\end{exe}


Here is a footnote.\footnote{This is a footnote.\begin{exe}
\ex
{
\gll Ein jeder Hund bellt.\\
{\sc art}.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} every.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} dog.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} bark.{\sc pres}.{\sc 3p}.{\sc sg}\\
\trans `Every dog barks.'
}
\label{ex-fn}
\end{exe}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect the `bidi` package, loaded by `polyglossia` for RTL languages, to be the culprit. Somewhere in `bidi`, the footnote numbering seems to get screwed up.

Comment: This code won't compile for me at all when `bidi` is loaded.

Comment: Sorry - I adapted my MWE. `\noautomath` was missing.

Comment: Since Alexis has already given you a fix for this the first part of your problem on the Ling-TeX mailing list, perhaps you can change your question to reflect just the `bidi` problem.  (It's really not so good to post the same question simultaneously on two separate forums, since people who don't read the mailing list will spend time trying to help solve a problem that has already been solved for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to both of your problems.  Since `gb4e` doesn't work properly in an RTL environment, there's no sense in patching the RTL footnotes.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Devanagari MT}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Nafees}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@footnotetext}{
    \@noftnotefalse\setcounter{fnx}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\roman{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
\apptocmd{\@footnotetext}{
    \@noftnotetrue
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\arabic{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
\@ifpackageloaded{bidi}{%
\pretocmd{\@LTRfootnotetext}{
    \@noftnotefalse\setcounter{fnx}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\roman{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
\apptocmd{\@LTRfootnotetext}{
    \@noftnotetrue
    \renewcommand{\thexnumi}{\arabic{xnumi}}
    }{}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a test.

\begin{exe}
\ex
{
\gll Ein jeder Hund bellt.\\
{\sc art}.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} every.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} dog.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} bark.{\sc pres}.{\sc 3p}.{\sc sg}\\
\trans `Every dog barks.'
}
\label{ex-1}
\end{exe}

Here is a footnote.\footnote{This is a footnote.\begin{exe}
\ex
{
\gll Ein jeder Hund bellt.\\
{\sc art}.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} every.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} dog.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} bark.{\sc pres}.{\sc 3p}.{\sc sg}\\
\trans `Every dog barks.'
}
\label{ex-fn}
\end{exe}}

\begin{exe}
\ex
{
\gll Ein jeder Hund bellt.\\
{\sc art}.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} every.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} dog.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} bark.{\sc pres}.{\sc 3p}.{\sc sg}\\
\trans `Every dog barks.'
}
\label{ex-1}
\end{exe}

Here is a footnote.\footnote{This is a footnote.\begin{exe}
\ex
{
\gll Ein jeder Hund bellt.\\
{\sc art}.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} every.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} dog.{\sc m}.{\sc sg}.{\sc nom} bark.{\sc pres}.{\sc 3p}.{\sc sg}\\
\trans `Every dog barks.'
}
\label{ex-fn}
\end{exe}}



\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]